# Реализация функции возведения в степень. С/С++

Tags: алгоритм, c, c++

Подскажите наилучший алгоритм для реализации функции возведения в степень (pow).

Comment: "наилучший" довольно расплывчато: самый быстрый для маленьких (фиксированных целых) на выбранной архитектуре *или* самый быстрый для больших целых (например, какие в криптографии используются) *или* самый точный для float,double аргументов в определённом диапазоне или [алгоритм, который использует наименьшее число умножений (теоретически интересный)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Addition-chain_exponentiation) *или* самый простой (для программиста) и тестированный алгоритм: вызвать [std::pow()](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/pow) итд.

Answer (score 5):

Может это и не лучший способ, но работает!

```
 long int pow(long int x, unsigned int n)
 {
    if (n==0)
        return 1;
    else if (n==1)
        return x;
    else if (n % 2 == 0 )
        return pow( x * x, n/2);
    else
        return pow( x * x, n /2)*x;
 }
```

Answer (score 4):

Уточняйте вопрос, или предыдущий ответ будет верным. Если необходимо вычислить вещественную степень числа, то формула b^x = exp(x*ln(b)). Если нужно реализовать и функции экспоненты, и натурального логарифма, пожалуйста, - раскладывайте их [по Тейлору](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ряд_Тейлора).

Comment: Тейлор один из самых неэффективных способов... Профессионалы используют ортогональные полиномы (обычно Чебышева)

Answer (score 4):

**Shortest code (:**

```
class big{/*реализация длинной арифметики*/};
big BinPow(big a, long long n){
    big res = big(1); // тут res = 1
    while (n) n & 1 ? (res *= a, --n) : (a *= a, n >> 1);
    reutn res;
}
```

Вообще здесь используются свойства:

1. a^n = a^(n/2) * a^(n/2) - для четных n;
2. a^n = a^(n/1) * a - для нечетных n.

Длинка для пафоса (:

Comment: а здесь не перепутаны свойства для честных и нечётных?

Comment: @malloc спасибо за замечание, исправил.

Answer (score 4):

Комментарий ко всем ответам. Что делать с переполнением? Нигде оно не анализируется.

Например библиотечная функция

```
double pow(double x, double y)
```

устанавливает errno в ERANGE

Answer (score 3):

Я бы реализовал тот же алгоритм, что и в первом ответе, но итеративно, не расходуя лишнее время на рекурсивный вызов и O(log n) памяти в стеке вызовов, и с небольшими оптимизациями. Следующий код работает только для целых неотрицательных n, при других значениях n используйте разложение в ряд Тейлора.

```
long int pow(long int x, unsigned int n)
{
    long int a = x, p = 1;
    while (n > 0)
    {
        if ((n & 1) != 0)
            p *= a;
        a *= a;
        n >>= 1;
    }
    return p;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Можно много проще:

```
int pwr (register int m, register int e)
{
    register int temp;
    temp = 1;

    for( ; e; e--)
        tempс= temp * m;

    return temp;
}
```

Answer (score -3):

```
int pow(int a,int n)
{
    if(n==0) return 1;
    else
        if(n==1) return a;
    else
        return pow(a+a, n-1);
}
```

Comment: Это умножение