# Возведение в степень

Tags: c++, алгоритм

Как быстро возвести целое число в целую степень, т.е. реализовать упрощённую функцию `pow` из `<cmath>`?

Comment: Глупый вопрос: а зачем???

Comment: @kff чеб <cmath> не подключать

Comment: А циклом не проще?

Comment: @kff сложная скорость

Comment: `algorithm` будет не быстрее.

Comment: смотря какой алгоритм

Comment: Любой. В `algorithm` для этого нет ничего подходящего.

Comment: По модулю, или просто?

Answer (score 4):

Все реализуется встроенными средствами. Гуглиться за минуту - [быстрое возведение в степерь](http://e-maxx.ru/algo/binary_pow). Там детально разобрано. Собственно сам код следующий:

```
int binpow (int a, int n) {
    int res = 1;
    while (n)
        if (n & 1) {
            res *= a;
            --n;
        }
        else {
            a *= a;
            n >>= 1;
        }
    return res;
}
```

Comment: Такой алгоритм лучше, когда основание float. В формате int всё детерминировано.

Comment: Простите за оффтоп, но чисто из интереса, какими средствами вы пользуетесь для компиляции кода?

Comment: Не поверите, компилятором! В случае с++ кода - gcc или сlang

Comment: Программа потрясает своим изяществом. Однако декремент n следует убрать и оператор else вместе со скобками - тоже. А содержимое этого else выполнять безусловно.

Comment: @YuriNegometyanov и получится: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/273/%D0%A0%D0%B5%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B2-%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8C-%D0%A1-%D0%A1?rq=1#1020

Comment: @sercxjo А повыше - ещё чуть-чуть проще. И на одно умножение поменьше

Answer (score 2):

Для x=2 - сдвигом единицы на y битов влево.
Если основание больше - использовать разложение по степеням x<sup>2<sup>t</sup></sup>.
Формат int требует четыре пары умножений (3<sup>31</sup>=617673396283947), 
64-битный формат - пять.

```
int power(int x, int y) {     
  int pow, result;
  if(x==2) return 1<<y;
  pow=x; 
  result = y&1 ? pow : 1;   
  pow*=pow;
  result *= y&2 ? pow : 1;
  pow*=pow;
  result *= y&4 ? pow : 1;
  pow*=pow;
  result *= y&8 ? pow : 1;
  pow*=pow;
  return y&16 ? result*pow : result;
}
```

P.S. Программы без цикла и с циклом на PHP (переделывать там почти нечего):

```
function power($x, $y) {     
  if($x==2) return 1<<$y;
  $pow = $x; 
  $result = $y&1 ? $pow : 1;   
  $pow*=$pow;
  $result *= $y&2 ? $pow : 1;
  $pow*=$pow;
  $result *= $y&4 ? $pow : 1;
  $pow*=$pow;
  $result *= $y&8 ? $pow : 1;
  $pow*=$pow;
  return $y&16 ? $result*$pow : $result;
}

function binpow ($a, $n) {
    $res = ($n & 1) ? $a : 1;
    while ($n){
        $a *= $a;
        if (($n>>=1) & 1) {
            $res *= $a;
        }
    }
    return $res;
}

printf("<br>x = %d &emsp; y = %d &emsp; x**y = %d &emsp; x**y = %d", $x=2, $y=15, power($x,$y), binpow($x,$y));
printf("<br>x = %d &emsp; y = %d &emsp; x**y = %d &emsp; x**y = %d", $x=6, $y=4, power($x,$y), binpow($x,$y));
printf("<br>x = %d &emsp; y = %d &emsp; x**y = %d &emsp; x**y = %d", $x=3, $y=10, power($x,$y), binpow($x,$y));
printf("<br>x = %d &emsp; y = %d &emsp; x**y = %d &emsp; x**y = %d", $x=5, $y=5, power($x,$y), binpow($x,$y));
```

Результаты:

```
x = 2   y = 15   x**y = 32768   x**y = 32768
x = 6   y = 4   x**y = 1296   x**y = 1296
x = 3   y = 10   x**y = 59049   x**y = 59049
x = 5   y = 5   x**y = 3125   x**y = 3125
```

Comment: я потестил Ваш код. При x=2 все конечно работает. Но уже при трех - нет. И при других числах также.

Comment: @KoVadim Уже работает (считала x^x). Благодарю.

Comment: Ээээ... А почему это вдруг число типа `int` ограничено 16-ю битами? Пишите честно, с циклом.

Comment: @VladD Пятью битами ограничена степень, в которую мы можем возвести int>2 без переполнения. Но умножений получается четыре пары =)

Comment: @Yuri: А если `int` 256-битный? В C++ разрядность `int`'а не фиксирована.

Comment: @VladD Для 64-5 пар умножений, для 128 - 6 пар, для 256 - 7 пар. Хотя 256-битная реализация - пока большая редкость.

Comment: @Yuri: 5 пар **чего**, простите? (В ответе есть слово «пара», но понятнее от этого не становится.)

Comment: @Yuri: Если бы вы написали цикл, вам не пришлось бы думать о точной битности.

Comment: И ещё, ваш код в случае переполнения молча выдаёт неправильный ответ, что, честно говоря, очень не комильфо.

Comment: Разница по сравнению с нагугленным алгоритмом - в степени двойки и фиксированной степени цикла. Свои плюсы, свои минусы.

Comment: @VladD Диагностика должна быть встроенной.

Comment: @Yuri: Не совсем понимаю, во что встроенной?

Comment: @VladD Значит. некомильфо. Но цикл дела не меняет.

Answer (score 0):

Я думаю, что так (проверял, работает), правда без дробного показателя степени, но с отрицательным

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    setlocale(0, "");


int a, n;
double fn_expon(int s, int f);

cout << "Введи число-основание степени:" << endl; cin >> a;
cout << "введи число-показатель степени:" << endl; cin >> n;
cout << "Результат=" << fn_expon(a, n) << endl;


return 0;
}
double fn_expon(int s,int f) {
  int i;
   double res = 1;
    while (s){
    if (!f) return res;

    for (i = 1; i <= abs(f); i++)
    res *= s;

  if (f < 0) {
    res = 1 / res; return res;
    }

return res;
}


return res;

}
```