# c++ Рекуррентные отношения

Tags: c++

У меня есть программа, я хочу заменить pow на цикл ( чтобы все работало также ). Я хочу  сделать так ,  чтобы определенный элемент в цикле ( j1, к примеру) вызывался только вместе с i1 ( а не так , что вначале проработает j весь, а потом весь i( использовав всю j). Или посоветуйте другой способ реализации моей идеи ( замены pow).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <limits.h>
#include <math.h>

using namespace std;

void fun(int n, int x0, int xm, double dx)
{
    double y = 0;
    int a = 1;

    for (double x = x0; x <= xm; x += dx)
    {
        for (int j = n; j >= 0; --j) // вместо этого цикла и a была функция pow 
        {
            a *= x0;
        }
        y = 0; 
        for (int i = n; i >= 0; --i)
        {
            y += (2 * i + 1) * a;
        }
        cout << " x =" << x << '\t' << "y=" << y << endl;
    }
}

int  main()
{

    int n, x0 = 2, xm = 4;
    double dx = 0.25;
    cin >> n;
    fun(n, x0, xm, dx);
}
```

Comment: прекрасно понимаю ваше желание не использовать функции (ну можно одну сделать fun для названия любого алгоритма), вы не один такой. но все таки. объявите функции pow, pow1, pow2, ... с разными [способами](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/273/%D0%A0%D0%B5%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B2-%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8C-%D0%A1-%D0%A1) возведения в степень и эксперементируйте.

Comment: я так понимаю, у вас задачка из спортивного программирования: вычислить для больших чисел за ограниченное время. ну так напишите в условии, для какого n у вас долго выполняется, или что ответ неверный. а то непонятен смысл вашей оптимизации. у вас линейная временная сложность алгоритма от n, куда уж быстрее?

Comment: Вынесите цикл `for (int j = n; j >= 0; --j)` перед циклом `for (double x = x0; x <= xm; x += dx)`  и будет как раз то, что вам нужно.

Comment: К сожалению это нето , y  - не изменяется. Я сам как-то попытаюсь похимичить.

Comment: Конечно не изменяется, вы его каждый раз обнуляете в строке `y=0`. Это тоже нужно делать один раз за пределами циклов.

Comment: да , это одна из ошибок , но даже при выносе y , y очень быстро изменяется. Или ( при x=0 ) он должен быть константой ( =1) , а он прыгает . Возможно , все намного проще , если мне получится реализовать , я отпишу здесь ответ.

Comment: У вас `y` от `x` вообще никак не зависит. Он зависит от `x0`, который у вас жестко задан в коде и никак не меняется. Учитывая формулу по которой вы рассчитываете `y`, он и должен быстро увеличиваться. Лучше озвучьте изначальное условие задачи. Сейчас это похоже на проблему [XY](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0_XY)

Comment: Да , вы правы от x0 ( он изменяется от приращения ) . Условие - найти сумму y = (2n+1)*x^n ( x принадлежит от 2 до 4 включительно).  При n = 0 , y = 1. //  n=1 , y=7 // n=2 , y = 27 .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <limits.h>
#include <math.h>

using namespace std;

void fun(int n, int x0, int xm, double dx)
{
 double y = 0;

 for (double x = x0; x <= xm; x += dx)
 {
  y = 0;
  for (int i = n; i >= 0; --i)
  {
   double var = 1;
   for(int j = 0;j < i; j++)
   {
    var *= x;
   }
   y += (2 * i + 1) * var;
  }
  cout << " x =" << x << '\t' << "y=" << y << endl;
 }
}

int  main()
{

 int n, x0 = 2, xm = 4;
 double dx = 0.25;
 cin >> n;
 fun(n, x0, xm, dx);
}
```

Суть моего ответа заключается в поиске аналога функции pow ( что я и сделал , заменил на цикл ) . В принципе все.

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Answer (score 0):

Посмотрим что выполняет цикл

```
  for (int i = n; i >= 0; --i)
    {
        y += (2 * i + 1) * a;
    }
```

это
**(n + 1) * a +  a * ( 0 + 2 * 1 + 2 * 2 + ... + 2 * n)**. И, так как ряд является простой арифметической прогрессией c количеством членов `n + 1` с `нулевым первым членом`, то из формулы

**Sn = (a1 + d * (n-1) /2) * n**, где   разность прогрессии d == 2,  и с учетом того, что вместо `n` имеем `n + 1`, то получим

**Sn = (a1 +  n ) * (n + 1) = n * (n + 1)**

и, соответственно

y = (n + 1) * a + a * n(n + 1), и упростив получим результат работы всего цикла простой формулой:

```
y = a *(n + 1) * (n + 1)
```

Так что ваш цикл вовсе не нужен

Comment: Извиняюсь за ожидание , к сожалению программа работает не так с вашим фрагментом. Вот таже программа только с pow (  игрек увеличивается при n=1 , на 0,75, при 2 на 5)

Comment: cpp.sh/6r3ht  вот ссылка на код с pow